80's TV episode (maybe 70's rerun) with a helicopter and grenades
I have this obscure memory of this TV show I saw when I was a kid.  In the episode, there were 2 guys in a helicopter and they were dropping grenades, but the grenades were exploding before they hit the ground (maybe it was a boat).  They just happened to have glass jars sitting there and put the grenades into the jars to hold the clip until it landed and broke the glass.  I swear I remember the helicopter had a mouth painted on it but I'm not sure that's the same show.  Any ideas what it was I saw?

Almost positive you're after Riptide from 1984. They had a helicopter with a huge mouth on it and I'm pretty sure there was an episode where they droppped Mason jar grenades like you described. I'll try and track it down for you. EDIT: Haven't found the particular episode yet, but found a mention of it here. In the meantime, here's the intro:




That has to be it. They were detectives or something and had a nerd frind with a robot. I think they said mayonaise jars though.
